# Detect if active directory user must reset his password through Java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

We have an active directory set up on a windows server (it is not a proper LDAP) and our application authenticates the users through the same.

I would like to know if the user is logging in for the first time to force him to reset his password.

We cannot maintain a flag at application level as the user may log in through any application which uses the same kind of authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got mislead with the scenario. If a user's "change password upon next login" flag is set, we get an error while logging in through Java.

Got the solution. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As per http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/use-get-aduser-determine-who-has-never-logged, the `lastLogonTimestamp` ldap attribute doesn't have a value if the user has never logged on. SO you can use this to determine if the user has even logged on.

Comment: The lastLogonTimeStamp is only guaranteed to replicate within 14 days. So it maybe correct on on DC and not on another.

Comment: @jeemster, Can you please elaborate a little, is it useful to take this path?

Comment: Pavan, Jeemster says that this attribute is guaranteed to be replicated only within 14 days. So when you have multiple DCs you may get an old value as its not yet been updated. The following link http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx suggests to use security logs if you want logon information in realtime

Comment: Like HYS said. You could get an old or no value form one DC and a current value from another.